# How do I configure spring-loaded with spring tc server?

Tags: spring-loaded, tcserver

I run my spring based web application using spring tc server. I run tc server from the command line.

```
D:\vfabric-tc-server-developer\base-instance\bin>tcruntime-ctl.bat run
```

I just came to know about spring loaded which is a JVM agent for reloading class file changes whilst a JVM is running. It transforms classes at loadtime to make them amenable to later reloading.

see more of spring loaded [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded)

I am not sure how do i configure it with the tc server.

Please help if anyone has used it?

Comment: does changing `java` tcruntime-ctl.bat  `java -javaagent:<pathTo>/springloaded-{VERSION}.jar -noverify SomeJavaClass work?
`

Comment: I'm thinking it should go into the setenv.sh (or whatever that is on windows). But I tried adding it to the JAVA_OPTS and still no dice

Comment: also, is springloaded already actually being used, I'm looking at the tcserver configuration page, and there is an option to "Enable Java Agent-based reloading"

Comment: When I used TCServer from my STS environment all changes I was making were being instantly hotswapped into the server, including adding new methods and classes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 
 I did find the answer here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded/issues/59

Basically if you're using a recent version of STS, it's got an early version of spring loaded in place, and you can enable it from the server configuration page with the option to "Enable Java Agent-based reloading".

I replaced the jar it was pointing to (go look at you updated run configuration to see the new parameters) with a recent version of springloaded, and it appears to be working.